# How to correctly access elements of a nested list in python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, nested

I am trying to evaluate and alter the elements of a nested list within nested for loops in python but my code breaks when I try to access list[i-1][j]

This works:

```
for i in range(HEIGHT):
    for j in range(WIDTH):

        if nested_list[i+1][j].foo == 'bar' and nested_list[i][j+1].foo == 'bar':
            nested_list[i][j].foo = 'bar'
```

but when I use i-1 or j-1 instead of +1 above it breaks (inserts bar as value for all elements)

```
for i in range(2, HEIGHT):
    for j in range(2, WIDTH):

       if nested_list[i-1][j].foo == 'bar' and nested_list[i][j-1].foo == 'bar':
           nested_list[i][j].foo = 'bar'
```

Edit:

the nested list holds a map like this:

```
##################
####.....#########
####.....#########
####.....#########
############....##
############....##
############....##
##################
```

when using the first bit of code the expected result occurs, the corners on the right hand side of the rectangles are turned into #s

when trying to do it 'the other way' i.e evaluating the left hand sides the whole array is populated with #s
(I hope that makes sense)

Comment: What does "my code breaks" mean? Do you get an exception? If so, copy and paste the traceback into your question. If you get the wrong results, show the expected and actual results. If something else happens, describe it.

Comment: Also, why are you _trying_ to use `i-1` here? What do you want it to do? Give us some stripped-down sample input and show us what you expect to happen.

Comment: there is no exception, the code works but produces unexpected results. All elements are set to 'bar' as if the if statement is ignored

Comment: Without knowing what the input data are and what output you expect and actually get, it's pretty much impossible to tell you why you're not getting the output you expect. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details on what to put in your question.

Comment: range(HEIGHT) goes from the first_height (0) to the last_height, right? So what's (first_height - 1) represent to you? Try range(1,HEIGHT)

Comment: After your edit, this still isn't a real example. Please read the MCVE link and do what it says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is because you're modifying the values of your nested list as you iterate over it. After you turn the top-left corner of an open space into a `#`, the open spaces to either side of it (right and down) now see themselves as being top-left corners too, and so get turned into `#`s when their turn comes. This doesn't happen when you're modifying the bottom left corner, because by the time you get to it, you've already processed the squares above and to its left.

To work around this issue, there are a few different approaches. The simplest might be to simply iterate in reverse, starting with `WIDTH` and `LENGTH` and counting down to `1`. However, this approach is similarly fragile (it will only work for the top-left square).

An alternative, which would be a bit more complicated but would work if you wanted to fill in any kind of of corner (not just the top left), would be to create a new nested list, rather than modifying the existing one. Because you're looking at the original list the whole time, you'll never see the results of previous operations when determining the appropriate value for a square.

Here's some code that uses a list comprehension to do this:

```
def is_corner(lst, i, j):
    return i >= 0 and j > 0 and lst[i-1][j] == "bar" and lst[i][j-1] == "bar"

new_nested_list = [["bar" if is_corner(nested_list, i, j) else nested_list[i][j]
                    for j in range(WIDTH)]
                   for i in range(HEIGHT)]
```

You can modify the `is_corner` predicate function however you want, and only the squares for which it returns `True` will have their values replaced. You could check for *any* corner with:

```
def is_corner(lst, i, j):
    return (0 < i < len(lst) and 0 < j < len(lst[0]) and
           (lst[i-1][j] == "bar" or lst[i+1][j] == "bar") and
           (lst[i][j-1] == "bar" or lst[i][j+1] == "bar"))
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, I was just working on a simplified version of the program to better explain what I was trying to accomplish but you've nailed it. Many thanks